# Oracle Query to derive all Id's whose balances have increased from consecutive 3 months along with there growth percent

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to extract all id's that have increased balances from last consecutive 3 months, and also display their growth percent

sample data set-- not all Id's will have consecutive 3 months of data. In that case derive growth percent from (what is available) most recent previous

```
ID   DATE    BAL
1   201904  81747.88
1   201905  90102.06
1   201906  131580.78
2   201904  47903.14
2   201905  51829.55
2   201906  57044.11
3   201904  43650.41
3   201905  47838.46
4   201906  204320.01
5   201905  528.92
5   201906  1158.07
6   201904  27236.02
6   201905  35019.5
6   201906  45228.87
```

Below is the sql i'm using to calculate the metrics, but something seem to be not working right, as my growth_prcnt is wrong. There should be a better way to derive this

```
    select (BAL-PREV_3MTNH_BAL)/PREV_3MTNH_BAL as grwth_prcnt, c.*  
    from(
      select b.* 
        from (
          select A.*, LAG(BAL, 3) over (partition by ID order by DATE) AS PREV_3MTNH_BAL,
            LAG(BAL, 2) over (partition by ID order by DATE) as PREV_2MTNH_BAL,
            LAG(BAL, 1) over (partition by ID order by DATE) as PREV_1MTNH_BAL
          from temp A ) b
        where BAL>PREV_3MTNH_BAL and  BAL>PREV_2MTNH_BAL AND BAL>PREV_1MTNH_BAL AND DATE >=201904)C
```

Comment: If you want 3 consecutive months then why you are skipping the last month data, which can be extracted using `LAG(BAL, 1) over (partition by ID order by DATE) AS PREV_MTNH_BAL` ?

Comment: updated, but still my growth_percent is wrong

Comment: can you specify the expected growth_percent for any one id. and the value which is generated from the query.

Comment: actually it is calculating previous months as well wrong for those id's that do not have all 3 months data

Comment: 3 consecutive month growth ==  `BAL > PREV_1MTNH_BAL and  PREV_1MTNH_BAL > PREV_2MTNH_BAL`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output you're expecting to see.

Comment: You should not consider the value of PREV_3MTNH_BAL, as there is no data for that month. As per the sample data, we have balance for the current, current-1(PREV_1MTNH_BAL) and current-2(PREV_3MTNH_BAL) months only.

Also, sample expected output will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your problem, Following should be the query:

```
-- CONSECUTIVE 3 MONTH DATA MUST BE
-- CURRENT MONTH (JUNE)
-- LAST MONTH (MAY)
-- LAST TO LAST MONTH (APRIL)
SELECT
    -- MULTIPLIED BY 100 BECAUSE IT IS PERCENTAGE AS NAME SUGGEST
    ROUND(((BAL - PREV_2MTNH_BAL) * 100) / PREV_2MTNH_BAL, 2) AS GRWTH_PRCNT,
    B.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            A.*, -- CURRENT MONTH DATA AND BALANCE
            LAG(BAL, 1) OVER(
                PARTITION BY ID
                ORDER BY
                    DATE
            ) AS PREV_1MTNH_BAL, -- LAST MONTH BALANCE
            LAG(BAL, 2) OVER(
                PARTITION BY ID
                ORDER BY
                    DATE
            ) AS PREV_2MTNH_BAL -- LAST TO LAST MONTH BALANCE
        FROM
            TEMP A
    ) B
WHERE
    -- CURRENT MONTH BALANCE MUST BE GREATER THAN LAST MONTH BALANCE
    BAL > PREV_1MTNH_BAL 
    -- LAST MONTH BALANCE MUST BE GREATER THAN LAST TO LAST MONTH BALANCE
    AND PREV_1MTNH_BAL > PREV_2MTNH_BAL
    AND DATE >= 201904
```

Cheers!!

Comment: If there is a chance of having 0 in balance column then handle the logic of finding a percentage accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have at most one row per month, then:

```
select (BAL - PREV_3MTNH_BAL) / PREV_3MTNH_BAL as grwth_prcnt,
       a.*  
from (select A.*,
             LAG(BAL, 3) over (partition by ID order by DATE) AS PREV_3MTNH_BAL,
             LAG(BAL, 2) over (partition by ID order by DATE) as PREV_2MTNH_BAL,
             LAG(BAL, 1) over (partition by ID order by DATE) as PREV_1MTNH_BAL,
             COUNT(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from temp A
      where date >= 201904
     ) a
where BAL > PREV_3MTNH_BAL and
      BAL > PREV_2MTNH_BAL and
      BAL > PREV_1MTNH_BAL and
      DATE = 201906 and
      cnt = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks for editing your post, however i get zero results, when i run your revised query